# Redirect site specific domain to a new extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My htaccess controls multiple domains (it's a custom CMS). I need to redirect all requests to my domain "mydomian.com.br" to "mydomain.org.br" This includes calls to sites such as "mydomain.com.br/contact".

I tried this but it just redirects everything to the homepage:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.org.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: quite a bit, yes.

Comment: Move this rule right at top just below `RewriteEngine` line

Comment: how will that affect my other rules then?

Comment: Didn't understand question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.org.br$1
```